# Isometry of bilinear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

This is [Corollary 1.3.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA9) from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*.

> **3.10 Corollary** Two bilinear spaces are isometric if and only if they have the same dimension and the same regular components.
>
> *Proof.* If $(V,b)$ and $(V,b_1)$ satisfy the hypotheses and if $$V=V^\bot\oplus W, \qquad V_1=V_1^\bot\oplus W_1$$
>   then $\alpha\oplus\beta\colon V\to V_1$ is an isometry where $\alpha\colon V^\bot\to V_1^\bot$ is an arbitrary isomorphism and $\beta\colon W\to W_1$ is an isometry.

I don't know how to show explicitly that direct sum satisfy isometry of bilinear space please help it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $V^\bot=\{x\in V; (\forall v\in V) b(x,v)=0\}$.

Any vector $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as $v=v_0+w_0$ where $v_0\in V^\bot$ and $w_0\in W$. Let us denote $\gamma=\alpha\oplus\beta$. We have
\begin{align*}
b_1(\gamma(v), \gamma(v')) 
&\overset{(1)}= b_1(\alpha(v_0)+\beta(w_0),\alpha(v'_0)+\beta(w'_0)) \\
&\overset{(2)}= b_1(\alpha(v_0),\alpha(v'_0))+b_1(\alpha(v_0),\beta(w'_0))+b_1(\beta(w_0),\alpha(v'_0))+b_1(\beta(w_0),\beta(w'_0)) \\
&\overset{(3)}= b_1(\beta(w_0),\beta(w'_0)) \\
&\overset{(4)}= b(w_0,w'_0) \\
&\overset{(5)}= b(v_0,v'_0)+b(v_0,w'_0)+b(w_0,v'_0)+b(w_0,w'_0) \\
&\overset{(6)}= b(v_0+w_0,v'_0+w'_0) \\
&\overset{(7)}= b(v,v')
\end{align*}
In steps $(2)$, $(6)$ we have simply used bilinearity.
Step $(4)$ is the fact that $\beta$ is isometry.
In step $(3)$ we used the fact that $\alpha(v_0),\alpha(v'_0)\in V_1^\bot$ which means that $b_1$ vanishes whenever these vectors are plugged into $b_1$.
Step $(5)$ is similar, just that we are using $b$ rather than $b_1$ and the fact that $v_0,v'_0\in V^\bot$.

Comment: What is meaning of arbitrary isomorphisam? Where we use isomorphisam alpha? In step 3 there is typo it should be beta instead of alpha I think?

Comment: You want to show that $\gamma$ is a bijective isometry, i.e. it is a linear isomorphism and it fulfills $b_1(\gamma v,\gamma v') = b(v,v')$. I only shown the latter.

Comment: for that beta should be isomorphisam also?

Comment: Yes. But we know that $\beta$ is isometry. (Hence it is linear isomorphism.) And you were right about the typo, I have corrected $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for detail answer.